# Which ports are used by Jgroups?

Tags: linux, port, wildfly-8, infinispan, jgroups

I'm using Wildfly 8 for my server, in my server I use Infinispan (which use Jgroups) for cluster cache. I want to know which ports that Jgroups/Infinispan uses, so I can open these ports for communicating between server nodes without disable my Linux firewall.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may find these answers in your `wildfly/standalone/configuration/` directory. I assume you are using `standalone-full-ha.xml` configuration:

```
<!-- By default you are using UDP stack -->
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:2.0" default-stack="udp">

<!-- Those ports are used for communication -->
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp" port="55200" multicast-address="${jboss.default.multicast.address:230.0.0.4}" multicast-port="45688"/>
<socket-binding name="jgroups-udp-fd" port="54200"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked with basic network command such us
$ netstat -a

you can find more examples in [binarytides](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-netstat-command-examples/)